# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException in InitializeComponent() (UserControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

For the **answer**, see below. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615550/6826935)

---

I am doing WPF development and got this error.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException error in
>   InitializeComponent();

Code excerpt: (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // Exception here
        this.DataContext = this;

        // UI stuff here, deleted
    }
```

The exception stated this

> Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '23' and line position '10'.

So here is the line 23-24 in related file (MainWindow.xaml)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cozyplanes.SudokuApp"

// UI stuff here..., deleted

<local:SudokuUserControl x:Name="SudokuGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" Height="451"
                              Loaded="SudokuGrid_Loaded" KeyUp="SudokuGrid_KeyUp" MouseLeftButtonUp="SudokuGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```

I have no idea why this is happening. MainWindow class is extending Window.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window { ... }
```

As a reference,
SudokuUserControl.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SudokuUserControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SudokuUserControl : Window { ... }
```

and in output

```
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Cozyplanes.SudokuApp.App.InitializeComponent'
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: does this matter? `Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`

Comment: `SudokuUserControl ` inherits from `Window`.  You can't add a `Window` as a child control.  If you want to actually use it as a control, it should inherit from `UserControl`, fixing that might involve more than just changing the base-class though.

Comment: so what should i fix from what to what?

Comment: You need implement `SudokuUserControl ` as a `UserControl`, not a `Window`.  It *might* be as easy as changing the `public partial class SudokuUserControl : Window` to `public partial class SudokuUserControl : UserControl`, modifying the root element of the XAML to `UserControl` and cleaning up the attributes that `UserControl` doesn't support.  Or it might be a LOT more difficult; its hard to say without seeing more of the code and XAML for  `SudokuUserControl `.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you so much. I completely forgot `modifying the root element of the XAML to UserControl`. It was set to  `Window`. Yeah, I was kinda tired.  Anyways, thank you so much! <3

Comment: If you already found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @LexLi done! thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer for the future~~~~~!!!!!!
(ok, I will shut up)

So the error happened in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // Exception here
    this.DataContext = this;

    // UI stuff here, deleted
}
```

It said it had an exception in line 23 of `MainWindow.xaml` which was

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Cozyplanes.SudokuApp"
```

// UI stuff here..., deleted

Now you would notice there is `SudokuUserControl` there.

MY project was made like this.
SudokuUserControl.xaml was top of MainWindow.xaml

```
MainWindow.xaml

|--- MainWindow.xaml.cs

SudokuUserControl.xaml

|--- SudokuUserControl.xaml.cs
```

`SudokuUserControl` stuff was referenced in `MainWindow.xaml` file.

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` file was extending `Window`, `SudokuUserControl.xaml.cs` was extending nothing.

So Bradley told me to check the root element of the file. 
I checked that out and found out the root element was `Window`, not `UserControl`.

So when you get `InitializeComponent()` error,  make sure you referenced the things in both `XAML` file and `XAML CS` files.

---

That's it for now. If you need questions, I will try to help you as much as possible! Hope it helps. And thanks, Bradly. You are a lifesaver. :P